# SSH random connect timeout

Tags: networking, ssh, timeout

I'm having a strange issue trying to connect to a server through SSH. More than 80% of times I get a connection timeout, but sometimes manages to connect.

I'm behind a router so everyone in the office has the same external IP, but somehow I get lots of connection timeouts, but one of the coworkers, who is running Windows + Putty, does not have the issue.

Example:

```
user@user-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Notebook ~ $ date; ssh -vvv root@srv.domain.com

Wed Mar 15 12:58:53 CET 2017
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "srv.domain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to srv.domain.com [122.55.66.77] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 122.55.66.77 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host srv.domain.com port 22: Connection timed out





user@user-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Notebook ~ $ date; ssh -vvv root@srv.domain.com

Wed Mar 15 12:58:59 CET 2017
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "srv.domain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to srv.domain.com [122.55.66.77] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 122.55.66.77 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host srv.domain.com port 22: Connection timed out



user@user-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Notebook ~ $ date; ssh -vvv root@srv.domain.com

Wed Mar 15 12:59:03 CET 2017
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "srv.domain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to srv.domain.com [122.55.66.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to srv.domain.com:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from srv.domain.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

I also tried to check if there is some info about the issue in /var/log/auth.log, but I cannot see anything when I try to connect and I'm getting the timeout.

The server responds well to ping, but I also tried to connect through telnet to the port 22, and same timeout.

Any ideas?

I'm running Linux Mint, and the server is under Debian Jessie.

Comment: Is  this something you can definitely replicate (or definitely cannot) from another location, using the same laptop? Are you using the same network as the 'Windows + putty' person, or might it be you are on a WIFI connection, and the windows host is wired? Is there a firewall on the SSH server?

Comment: To debug, launch tcpdump on both sides (yours & the server) and see how the messages go to infer if the remote end does not see your packets or instead if you are not receiving remote packets

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact issue.

But it turns out my RSA key was the culprit. I was using RSA with a key length of 4096 bit. After changing my private key to ed25519, I did not face the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a DNS issue. Try to disable dns resolution in the ssh server.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UseDNS no
```